# Focus a window in GVIM if already open

Tags: ubuntu, vim

In case a .c file is already open, how can we focus to that file, when we again double click on that file? Currently, GVIM gives a warning that the file can only open in "read-only" mode, because a .swp file already exists for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means, either you have already opened the same file in vim/gvim, or you opened the file in vim/gvim last time and stopped vim/gvim abnormally.

**Case one**: check if the file has been opened already, find the vim process, do a `:ls` in vim to see if your file is sitting in buffer list. And switch to the buffer.

**Case two**: rm the swp file. and open it again.

**suggestion**, even if using gvim, try using one vim process to handle multiple files, it makes opertions/actions among files (e.g. cp/paste diff etc) a lot easier, don't open 10 files, in 10 vim processes. You will be lost.